# Use formula to copy cell values to another sheet if certain condition is satisfied

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula such that I can create a sub list in another sheet based on certain criteria. 
I have two columns in sheet1 A & B. I want to copy a value from cell B to the new list in sheet2 only if corresponding cell in A satisfies certain criteria. Please tell how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a formula to copy cell values to another as they can only affect the one they are written in (generally)...
However, you can write a formula in Sheet2 to pull data from Sheet1 based on a condition...
For example, the array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(FIND("o",LOWER(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4))),9999,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4)),ROW())),"")
```

In this example, I'm using the condition "the value in column A contains the letter 'o' - case insensitive"... Let me explain from the inside out...

- `ISERROR(FIND("o",LOWER(...)))` would give us `FALSE` if the value has an 'o', `TRUE` otherwise
- Rather than just giving a single value, we are working on the array of cells `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4` (which could be extended as you needed) - so this gives us an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values
- `IF(ISERROR(...),9999,ROW(...))` means that if there was no 'o' we will get the value 9999, otherwise we get the row number of the cell in the array - so this gives us an array of a mix of `9999` and row numbers
- `SMALL(...,ROW())` lets us pick out one of those values from the array - in this case the items in size order, and we are using `ROW()` as our counter (i.e. in Sheet2!A1 - `ROW()` is 1 and we get the smallest value from the array)... if we had a header row, we could do `ROW()-1` for example... Effectively we are indexing through a sorted list of row numbers in Sheet1 that match our condition
- `INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4,...)` is going to give us the value from column B in Sheet1 relating to our position in the list of matching rows
- Sometimes we have our 9999 (for all the cells that didn't match the condition - these are sorted to the end of the list with `SMALL`) and so the `INDEX` will give us an error... the index is outside the range. So we can replace it with a blank

Hope this makes some sense! Good luck! And remember to enter array formulas with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>...